# (Proof verification) Prove that the set $\{w,v_1,v_2,...,v_r\}$ is linearly independent.

Tags: solution-verification, vector-spaces

Problem: Let $S=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_r\}$ be a linearly independent subset of a vector space $V(F)$. If $w\in V$ such that $w\notin L(S)$, then prove that the set $S_1=\{w,v_1,v_2,...,v_r\}$ is also linearly independent.

Attempt: Let $\alpha_1w+\alpha_2v_1+\alpha_3v_2+...+\alpha_{r+1}v_r=0$ where $\alpha_i\in F,1\leq i\leq r$

Then,      $\alpha_1w=-\alpha_2v_1-\alpha_3v_2-...-\alpha_{r+1}v_r$

$\Rightarrow w=-\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_1}v_1-\frac{\alpha_3}{\alpha_1}v_2-...-\frac{\alpha_{r+1}}{\alpha_1}v_r$

However, we know that $w\notin L(S).$ Therefore $\alpha_i=0 \ \forall\ 1\leq i\leq r.$

Therefore set $S_1$ is linearly independent.

Is my proof correct and sufficient as in I missed a particular case?

Comment: Yes that is correct! At least the substance, then you should assume $\alpha_1\neq 0$ in order to have your implication, and also see what happens in the other case

Comment: You have the right idea, but your proof can’t be right because it never uses that $S$ is linearly independent.  Use that assumption to prove that $\alpha_1 \neq 0$.